# Nodejs + MongoDB how to restrict data for specific user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, schema

I have a new mongodb Schema

```
let TestTable = new Schema({
  Title: String,
  Content: String,
});
```

This is the post method to add data :

```
 api.post('/add',authenticate, (req, res) => {
    let NewTestTable = new TestTable ();
    NewTestTable.Title = req.body.Title;
    NewTestTable.save(err => {
        if (err) {res.send(err);}
        res.json({message: "Addig was sucessfully"});
    })
```

let say i logged in and i have user id 
how can i add new data for this schema only for specific user

and when i making a GET method i will receive only the data for this user

Get :

```
 api.get('/', authenticate,(req, res) => {
    TestTable.find({}, (err, testtable) => {
        if (err) {res.send(err);}
        res.json(testtable);
    });
```

thanks !

Comment: can you explain it a bit more? Question is too confusing.

Comment: let say i have two users 
both of them needs to use the testtable schema to adding new data to the database 
i want to restrict the data for a specific user 
if the user1 will make a get method he will receive only the data he added

Answer (score 0):

you need to take a reference of user in your TestTable Schema so by this you can just add the data and while searching your data just need to get the data with a condition of your userId for update you can use the specific document id of your TestTable Schema.

Ex:

```
let TestTable = new Schema({
  Title: String,
  Content: String,
userId:{type:Schema.ObjectId,ref:"userId",default:null},

});
```

Comment: ohhh thanks ... but when i making a post  method
what i need to do ? 
    NewTestTable.userId= req.body.userId?